# Why can I clone from the command line but not a bash script?

Tags: git, bash, github

I want to clone an open, public repo into a different directory.  To do this from the command line I type:

`git clone git@github.com:computersarecool/dotfiles.git documents/gitprojects/dotfiles`

which works.

However, now I want to do it from a `bash` script.  In the script I have literally the exact same code:

```
#!/bin/bash
git clone git@github.com:computersarecool/dotfiles.git documents/gitprojects/dotfiles
```

but now I get an error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).                                            
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Can anyone explain the issue to me? I do not even understand why it is asking for a publickey in the first place as the repo is open.

Comment: Are you doing this with `sudo` or as a different user or from `cron` or somesuch?

Comment: I am running the bash script as `sudo`!  Is there a way to account for this?

Comment: `git clone git@github.com:...` is connecting over SSH. It has to authenticate to the remote SSH daemon **before** it's able to talk to anything git-specific, so whether the repo is authenticated or not is completely irrelevant: it hasn't finished transport-layer negotiation and authentication at the point when it fails, so whether there's any kind of application-layer access control or not is moot.

Comment: Is there a reason for using sudo to clone it?

Answer (score 3):

If it is indeed a public open repo, use https instead of ssh:

```
#!/bin/bash
git clone https://github.com/computersarecool/dotfiles.git documents/gitprojects/dotfiles
```

If you want to stick to ssh, you should let ssh-agent know about your id_rsa key:

```
#!/bin/bash
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add /home/<Your username>/.ssh/id_rsa
git clone git@github.com:computersarecool/dotfiles.git documents/gitprojects/dotfiles
```

Add your username (and check the contents of the ~/.ssh directory to verify that your private key is named id_rsa)

Comment: You're still using `https://` in the second snippet, making the SSH key setup rather moot.

Answer (score 0):

You mention in your comments that you run the bash script as sudo.

I am going to guess that you cloned in the command line without sudo.

The error message `Permission denied (publickey).` is basically saying that the user trying to clone does not have the correct ssh public key. This is because **EACH AND EVERY USER** on a unix system will normally have their own ssh public key. Presumably your user has been configured to authenticate with github using your public key. But sudo runs as the user `root`. If you haven't configured root's public key to be used with a github account (either root's own github account or yours) then it will fail authentication.

You basically have 2 solutions for this:

1. Copy your public key to root's `.ssh` directory. This is not recommended! But for a single user machine like your own laptop the security risk of doing this is minimal.
2. Create a public key for root and register it with github.

Alternatively clone using https instead of ssh (pushing would be a pain though as it will require you to key in your password every time).

Yet another alternative is clone as yourself, not root.

Comment: You mention `public key` here but I am assuming the root user would need a public and private key correct?

Comment: Yes, that's how the key pair works. But never expose the private key to anyone else.

Comment: ...re: "pushing will be a pain" -- there's no obligation to push via the same URL one cloned with.